# Fill a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, mysql, dictionary, hashmap

I know my question is so silly and we found a lot's of resources on internet, but as a beginner i hesitate between two declaration to fill a HashMap in Java:

I have a MySQL request looking like this :

`select coordinates,x, y,z from log`

i want to fill a Map or a HashMap( whatever) with the values of x,y and z for each coordinates point.

that's what i did :

```
List<Map<String, Object>> res = h.select("select coordinates,x, y,z from log");
```

i never used Maps in Java, so i don't know if it's the good way to get an organized map.
So now i hesitate between the declaration above and this one:

```
Map<String,Map<String, Object>>
```

I really don't know with one i have to use **and how i can read the map after** .

Thank You

Comment: Could you specify what is `h`? It is probably returning a ResultSet and you need to create your Map or List of Maps out of the ResultSet.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Map and not a simple List<Coordinate> where coordinate is a wrapper class for x,y,z? That would be the OOP way to go about this.

Comment: What type is `h` of? Also, you should create a class `coordinates` and declare the map as follows: `Hashmap<String, Coordinates> = new Hashmap<String, Coordinates>();`

Comment: h is the database handle, i use JDBI:        IDBI handle = dbService.getHandle();
    Handle h = handle.open();

Comment: i am not using map for specific reason, but i though it's the best way to treat this kind of data , i have to get the coordinates to each point and then pass them as parameters for a function

Comment: @LuigiEdlCarno Thank you i think you gave the best solution, i haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 0):

in case you need this data structure afterward for getting (X,Y) coordinated by Z then the second choice would give you quick access.
Map = Map.get(key); 
Otherwise you will have to loop throw the list.
If this is not the case a simple ArrayList should be fine. 
In any case see more details here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html